# The probability to log on a computer from a remote terminal is 0.7.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The probability to log on a computer from a remote terminal is $0.7$. Let $X$ denote the number of attempts that must be made to gain access to the computer.
Find:

(a) The distribution of $X$ and prove that is correctly defined

A:geometric distribution,f:N->(0;1]

(b) The expected value of attempts needed to gain access

A:f(k)=0.7*0.3^(k-1)

(c) The probability that at most three attempts, respectively at least two attempts must be made to gain access.

A:f(3)=0.7*0.3^2

A:f(2)=0.7*0.3

Can someone help me with this problem? I don't know what kind of distribution should I pick for $X$. Can someone tell me if my answer are rights ?

That's all the info I've got for the problem.

Comment: Hint: (a) $X$ is geometric.  (b) there's a simple formula for the mean of a geometric, (c) sum of the geometric over a subset of the range.

Comment: Good point you definitely need independence but I'm guessing that's almost certainly assumed here.

Comment: To conclude it is the geometric distribution, we need to assume that the results (success/failure) on various attempts are independent.  As we know from experience, there are difficulties with that model, unless the attempts are made at fairly widely separated times. But you are expected to assume independence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you ask for guidance and not the complete anawer: (a) $X$ is geometric.  (b) there's a simple formula for the mean of a geometric, (c) sum of the geometric over a subset of the range.

You see how $X$ is like flipping a coin over and over till you get a head?  But the coin is not a fair coin it's $0.7$ heads $0.3$ tails.  That's the basic formula for a geometric.

Comment: For (c) I should use the average value formula or the variation formula ?

Comment: @Netheru $p(X\leq4)=p(X=1)+p(X=2)+p(X=3)+p(X=4)$.  Each of those terms is easy to calculate for a geometric, just plug into the formula for the probability distribution function with $\lambda=0.7$.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time !

Comment: No problem.  For the second part of (c) it's easier to compute the probability that it doesn't happen and subtract from one.  In other words compute $1-p(X\leq1)$